# Check hover event in inspect element of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Can any one help me how to check hover event in Google Chrome inspect element like we see in Mozilla Firefox inspect element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following images are shamelessly ripped from [“Inspect” a hover element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602611/inspect-a-hover-element) and [See :hover state in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools). :)

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]